# Authentication issues when pushing packages to internal Azure Dev Ops package feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli, azure-artifacts

I am having trouble figuring out how to authenticate and push packages to the private Azure Dev Ops - Artifacts feed. I have a hunch that [this](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) is what I am looking for but not too sure how it is used exactly when using `dotnet nuget push`. The documentation only shows you how to use it when consuming packages and not when publishing packages to a private nuget feed (like Artifacts).

When using the `DotNetCoreCLI@V2` task with the environment variable `system.debug` set to true (to increase log verbosity) I see that behind the scenes there is url that is retrieved as the feed url.

It looks like this within the build task

`sr/bin/dotnet nuget push /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/{ProjectName}/bin/Release/{MyPackage}.0.4.5-alpha-1911.nupkg --source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{MyOrganisation}/_packaging/7064a25a-fa3a-7dc1-a8cb-9d05a01100ef/nuget/v3/index.json --api-key VSTS`

The source url seems to be generated on each build as unique and I'm thinking that this is has something to do with my problem. The feed itself lists the feed url as `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{MyOrganisation}/_packaging/{MyProject}/nuget/v3/index.json` when go to feed options on Azure Dev Ops itself.

So nothing worked unfortunately. I was thinking that it would be great if I could use a private access token (PAT) to authenticate myself to the internal nuget feed.

I am figuring this out because I need to get this to work both in an outside of azure dev ops, so using the azure pipelines task is no good in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this successfully using NuGet.exe (`nuget push` as opposed to `dotnet nuget push`).

On the Feed page, click the "Connect to Feed" button. There is a link there to "Download NuGet + Credential Provider". In the zip file, there will be a copy of NuGet.exe and CredentialProvider.VSS.exe. Extract them to the same folder.

When you run `nuget push` from that directory (copy the command syntax from the same page where it says "Push a package", substituting your .nupkg file name) the CredentialProvider prompts you for your credentials and handles the rest for you. The CredentialProvider.VSS.exe needs to be in the same directory as NuGet.exe

Comment: does this also work crossplat? (unix boxes). Also how can I do this without a prompt? ie non-interactive / headless modes

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. Haven't tried it. My guess is no. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/extensibility/nuget-cross-platform-authentication-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the pointer there, I will try this and if it fails I will result to an official response from an azure pipelines dev found here -> https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/issues/107

I will post an answer when im done